# ArgumentError in method with only named parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have quite weird behavior of the method with only named parameters.

```
class MyConsumer < ...

  def method1(params)

    method2(params.slice(:a,:b))        
  end

  def method2(a:, b:)
    # do something
  end

end
```

I have test that works against method1 and works just ok. However on production I am getting `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` exception.

I tried to add

```
params = params[0] if params.instance_of?(Array)
```

As first line of `method1`, thinking that it is being called with an array instead of a hash, but that did not help.

Any insight on why calling method2 with `hash.slice` working in some cases and isn't in others?

Comment: Do your `params` hash always has `:a` and `:b` keys?

Comment: Where do you get the error. The problem is not that you expect 1 argument and you pass 0, it is opposite. You expect 0 arguments but pass 1. The source of the problem may not be in this method2

Comment: @Pavan how could that ever matter?

Comment: @mudasobwa I misunderstood the  question, spare me :)

Comment: Can you give examples of what exactly is being passed into method1 as parameters?

Comment: @Pavan yes, although when they doesn't it is another exception

Comment: @Nermin I am getting error exactly as stated. stack trace is  `def ... ` line of method2 and call of `method2` inside `method1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ActionController::Parameters#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-slice) returns an `ActionController::Parameters` instance, not a hash. It quacks like a hash, but it is not a hash, hence it could not be passed as is to the method, expecting double-splat.

Explicitly call [`to_hash`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bdc73a438a97f2e0aceeb745f4a95f95514c4aa6/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L254) on them before passing:

```
method2(params.permit(:a,:b).to_hash)
```

Please check the comments below for why it’s `permit`, not `slice`. Credits to @SimpleLime.

Comment: This is assuming he using ActionConroller::Parameters, which may not be the case, the only thing we can gather from the question above is that he has named his parameters for method1 as params

Comment: `to_hash` seems to throw an error unless you're dealing with a permitted hash (can use `permit(:a, :b)` instead of `slice(:a, :b)` as the simplest way). Assuming this is indeed, an `ActionController::Parameters`

Comment: @SimpleLime indeed, thanks, I have the answer updated accordingly.

Comment: @JohnHayes-Reed negative. From the error message it’s clear that `params.slice` method returns an object rather than a hash. Among all `slice` methods in both Ruby and Rails, only `ActionController::Parameters#slice` returns an object. Of course there could be a possibility, that OP invented his own `slice`, but I bet in this case the question would not be stated that way.

Comment: @SimpleLime let me try this

Comment: @mudasobwa ahh yes i see what you are saying!

Comment: ok, am going to take a pause for several hours since I can't test it right away. Will accept answer if that was the case with ActionController::Parameters